# How to slow the speed of my sprite in spriteKit swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a small game using spriteKit, my sprites are falling from from up to down in a high speed, i want to manage the time. I know there is a way, SKaction can do this. but i do not know how to implement this function.

this is my Code:

```
    var item: SKSpriteNode?;    
    item!.zPosition = 3;
    item!.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
    item!.position.x = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: minX+10, secondNum: maxX+10);
    item!.position.y = 500;
```

This is running perfectly, but speed of my falling sprites is very high for me, but when i am trying this, this give me error.
     type of SKaction is not assign to type CGFLoat. an

```
item!.position.y = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:500), duration: (2));
```

So please help me here, how to handle this.

Comment: position property is a `CGPoint`. `CGPoint` is a structure and it has two properties, `x` and `y` which are `CGFloat`. You can't assign `SKAction` instance to a `CGFloat` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use physics to move your objects if need be, but if you have no need for physics or collision detection using physics it may not be necessary. Your error is occurring because you cannot apply an SKAction to property that expects a CGFloat. If you want to use an SKAction to move the object you run it like so...

```
item!.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:500), duration: (2)));
```

Comment: Yes I am using physics, Can you tell me which function should I  use to add gravity to the object and How?

Comment: you say the game is running perfectly...How are you moving the objects right now?

Answer (score 1):

With `sprite-kit`, image it's a real world, so if you want to slow down the falling, you need to set `gravity`, with a "lighter" `gravity`, item will fall slower.

[Spritekit tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners)

Comment: This only relevant if you assume that he is using physics to move and control his objects